# How does $\frac12\sqrt{n^2 + \frac{4m^3}{27}}$ become $\sqrt{\frac{n^2}4 + \frac{m^3}{27}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> $$\begin{align}
> &\frac n2 \pm   \frac12 \,\sqrt{n^2 + \frac{4m^3}{27}}\\[6pt]
> =\; &\frac n2 \pm \phantom{\frac12}\sqrt{\frac{n^2}4 + \frac{m^3}{27}}
> \end{align}$$

Can someone please explain me how this radical multiplied by $1/2$  becomes this? You can see $1/2$ disappeared, and division by $4$ appeared under square root.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\frac{\sqrt{x}}2=\sqrt{\frac{x}{4}}$ for $x\geq0$.

Comment: (For non-negative $a$) We have $a = \sqrt{a^2}$, so $\frac12=\sqrt{\left(\frac12\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac14}$.

Comment: Thanks man. Now i understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By one of the laws of exponents $$a^mb^m=(ab)^m,$$

we have
$$\frac12\sqrt{k}=\sqrt{\bigg(\frac12\bigg)^2}\sqrt{k}=\sqrt{\frac14}\sqrt{k}=\sqrt{\frac14k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since it is $$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n^2+\frac{4m^3}{27}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left(n^2+\frac{4m^3}{27}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{4}+\frac{4m^3}{4\times27}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember these: $$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$$

And note that:
$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{4}}$$

So:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{4}}\sqrt{n^2+\frac{4m^3}{27}} = 
\frac{\sqrt{1}\sqrt{n^2+\frac{4m^3}{27}}}{\sqrt{4}} =
\frac{\sqrt{1(n^2+\frac{4m^3}{27})}}{\sqrt{4}} =
\sqrt{\frac{1(n^2+\frac{4m^3}{27})}{4}} = 
\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{4}+\frac{m^3}{27}}
$$